# Como configurar Debugger de c++ en visual studio code?

Tags: c++, vscode

mi pregunta es sencilla, pero llevo tiempos tratando de resolverlo y no he podido, quiero poder usar el debugger que trae vsCode, pero no me funciona,cuando digo "No me funciona", me refiero:
Cuando ingreso a la parte del debugger y le doy correr, Supuestamente corrio el debugger, pero el problema esta en que pongo breakpoints, y no se detiene el programa en los breakpoints, simplemente corre todo y listo, entonces supongo que no lo tengo bien configurado, porque no se me detiene en los breakpoints, he leido la documentacion acerca del debugger, pero nunca he econtrado solucion, e igual he leido en otros lados y nunca he ecnontrado solucion

y quisiera la ayuda de alguien que sepa como hacerlo, porque lo ocupo,gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: "*Quiero usar el debugger que trae vsCode, pero no me funciona*" Eso es una descripción MUY VAGA de tu problema, sin más detalles es imposible ayudarte. Por favor, extiende la descripción de "*no me funciona*" y echa un vistazo a la [documentación de VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

Comment: Lo acabo de editar, espero que con esa descripcion sea lo suficiente para que me puedas ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

te comento mi caso, sobre como pude hacer debug de un programar "holaMundo" escrito en C utilizando Visual Studio Code, sobre OSX

- Primer instale la extensión **[C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)**
- Luego compilé el archivo en modo debug con:
  $ gcc holaMundo.c -o holaMundo --debug
- Luego, añadí al debuger la configuración nueva para c/c++ del tipo **(lldb) Launch** con:

```js
 {
        "name": "holaMundo",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/holaMundo",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "lldb"
    },
```

Te paso la captura del IDE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el mismo se ve, la ejecución del comando de compilación con debug, el contenido del archivo de configuracions del launch y el breakpoint activado

Una aclaración importante: En tipo, estoy dejando **"type": "cppdbg"** porque en mi caso utilizo OSX, pero si utilizaras windows, creo que aparece **cppvsdbg**

La consulta hacía referencia a C++, pero respondí en base a un archivo en C ya que el plugin de VSCode es el mismo para C/C++ y supongo que el procedimiento también debería ser el mismo.

Por último, si quisieras ampliar como utilizar el debugger, un buen [link es el oficial de vscode y debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_breakpoints)

Espero que ayude la respuesta
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

supongo que el problema se debe a una mala configuración del archivo `launch.json`, en el siguiente ejemplo mi archivo se llama `Main.cpp` y la configuración es esta en Windows:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda que el programa empieza a correr en una consola externa a la de VSCode, también la guía de Microsoft no esta actualizada con respecto a las nuevas versiones de la extensión de C/C++.

Si aún tienes dudas sobre la instalación y configuración completa tengo una guía que actualizo constantemente en Medium https://medium.com/pairzero/c-cpp-en-visual-studio-code-63e49a14c928 con los cambios importantes introducidos con las nuevas versiones de la extensión.